# marker issue for google map Geocoder(both current and previous location marker appear at the same time)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

here i am trying to create a map which will show a marker icon on desired location.it will get address from a input text field and show it on the map using google map Geocoder.But during first input it works fine.On second attempt two markers appear on the screen.one is for the new location and the other is for the previous location.how the marker for previous location can be removed.i am  using pure javascript here.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccp026sg/1/)

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src=' http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false '></script>
<style>
#mapholder{
   width:400px;
   height:400px;
   border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='textarea' placeholder="input area here" id='text'>
<input type='button' value='get address' onClick='getPosition("text");'>
<div id='mapholder'></div>
<script>
var map;
var geocode;
var mycenter=new google.maps.LatLng(25.58404,83.57702);
function init(){
    geocode=new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var map_prop={
      zoom:10,
      center:mycenter,
      mapeTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'),map_prop);
   var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
     position:mycenter,
     animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE

   });
   marker.setMap(map);
}
function getPosition(el){
   var area=document.getElementById(el).value;
   geocode.geocode({'address':area},function(result,status){
       if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            map.setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
            var newMarker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:result[0].geometry.location,
                map:map
            });
       }else{
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

       }
   });

}
window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `marker` global accessible(remove the `var`-keyword) and only set the position inside `getPosition`

```
marker.setPosition(result[0].geometry.location);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccp026sg/2/